# How to Pass message from Uipath to the web browser

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity, uipath-api

I am facing an issue in following activity:

1. I'm comparing the data in **Uipath**
2. After compared data, I will get the result
3. Now send this **result** or **message back** to the **web page** **using Uipath**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page has a form, then you can use the [Type Into](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/type-into) activity to type it back to wherever you want.

Comment: without using Type Into  Activity its possible to send message or data

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it's also possible to send requests directly to the server using the HTTP Request activity.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the **"Type Into"** activity
2. Click **"Indicate On Screen"** to select the field you want to Type Into on the web browser
3. On the right properties tab, key in the variable(string) or string in the Text (Under Input)

Answer (score 0):

As beginner you should be using always the Recording button. It's simple and easy to use.

So click on **Recording**

[image]

and now if you want to type something in the browser, select the **Web**

[image]

Now do all your stuff and finally hit the **Save & Exit** button

[image]